# Ошибка соответствия в классе - Could not find a match for class

Tags: c++builder

Здравствуйте.

---

Вот запрограммирован класс хранящий инфу о военных: ФИО и Возраст.

```
class Military
{ private: char FIO; int Age;
public:
Military(char FIOName, int A):FIO(FIOName),Age(A){};
Military(){};
~Military(){};
char get_FIO(){return FIO;};
int get_Age(){return Age;};
void set_F(char FIOName){FIO=FIOName;};
void set_Age(int A){Age=A;};
```

---

Его потомок - Рядовой: (год службы, род войск + ФИО и возраст из родительского класса **Military**)

```
class Soldier: public Military
{ private: int YearOfServ; char TypeOfForces; //год служб. род войск
public:
Soldier(int YOS, char TOF, char FIOName, int A):
Military(FIOName),Military(A),YearOfServ(YOS),TypeOfForces(TOF){};
Soldier(){};
~Soldier(){};
int get_YearOfServ(){return YearOfServ;};
char get_TypeOfForces(){return TypeOfForces;};
void set_YearOfServ(int YOS){YearOfServ=YOS;};
void set_TypeOfForces(char TOF){TypeOfForces=TOF;};
}
```

---

При попытке скомпилить, выдается ошибка:
**Could not find a match for 'Military::Military(char)'**
в строке

```
Military(FIOName),Military(A),YearOfServ(YOS),TypeOfForces(TOF){};
```

И в ней же ошибка **Base class 'Military' is initialized more than once**

---

И все бы ничего, дав вот из методички пример работает отлично, хотя там все так же, только не военные, а геометрические фигуры.

---

Родитель:

```
 class Figure
    {private: int Color;//поле класса, доступное только классу
    public://методы класса, доступные классам-потомкам и программе
    Figure(int PC):Color(PC){};
    Figure(){};
    ~Figure(){};
    int get_Color(){return Color;};
    void set_Color(int PC){Color=PC;};
    virtual AnsiString Info()
    {AnsiString res;
    switch (Color) {
    case 1:res="красный"; break;
    case 2:res="оранжевый"; break;
    case 3:res="желтый";break;
    case 4:res="зеленый"; break;
    case 5:res="голубой"; break;
    case 6:res="синий"; break;
    case 7:res="фиолетовый"; break;
    };return res;};
```

---

Потомок: (Круг, где Х,Y-координаты центра, R - радиус)

```
class Circle: public  Figure
{private: int X,Y,R;
public:
Circle(int PX,int PY,int PR,int PC):
Figure(PC),X(PX),Y(PY),R(PR){}
Circle(){}
int get_X(){return X;}
int get_Y(){return Y;}
int get_R(){return R;}
void set_X(int PX){X=PX;};
void set_Y(int PY){Y=PY;};
void set_R(int PR){R=PR;};
}
```

---

В строке

```
Circle(int PX,int PY,int PR,int PC):Figure(PC),X(PX),Y(PY),R(PR){}
```

Точно так же идет обращение к параметру **РС** определяющему цвет, через указание класса которому принадлежит этот параметр **Figure(PC)**
И подобных ошибок как у меня не возникает.

Comment: у Вас в классе Military определены конструктор без параметров и конструктор с 2-я (char и int), а вы вызываете конструктор с одним параметром char, который не определен

Comment: Спасибо огромное)

Comment: да, или определить такой Military(char FIOName):FIO(FIOName){};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у Вас в классе Military определены конструктор без параметров и конструктор с 2-я (char и int), а в потомке вы вызываете конструктор с одним параметром char, который не определен.

Нужно либо вызвать в `Soldier Military(FIO, A)`, либо определить `Military(char FIOName):FIO(FIOName){}`.

Answer (score 1):

Не **char**, а **char***, повсюду.

Comment: Cannot convert 'AnsiString' to 'char *'

Я поставил AnsiString повсюду)

Comment: Это не всегда годится. Придется добавлять ".c_str()" для функций, где требуется именно char*. Наример Application->MessageBoxA(...) и для ввода/вывода.